# pointer argument receiving address in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, address-operator

```
int y=5;
int *yPtr = nullptr;
yPtr = &y;
```

I understand that the pointer stores the address of y. and calling *yPtr dereferences y.

If I have a call to the void function:

```
int main()
{
    int number = 5;
    function( &number );
}

void function( int *nPtr)
{
    *nPtr = *nPtr * *nPtr;
}
```

if the function takes a pointer as argument, how can the call to the function use an address?
I understand that nPtr stores addresses but why couldn't it be defined as.

```
void functions (int &ref)
{
    ref = ref * ref;
}
```

My main question would be: Why does a function receiving an address argument need a pointer parameter to receive the address?

Comment: I guess that is how the standard is written. Even though references mostly work as pointers, you don't initialize them with a address, you initialize them with the value of a variable. The compiler does the same in both cases probably.

Comment: So you're asking why you need to explicitly pass an address, rather than the compiler implicitly doing it for you as it does with the pass-by-reference case?

Comment: I'm wondering why the function passes an address argument but has a pointer parameter.

Comment: because a pointer holds an address... recall that pointer behave exactly like any other ordinary types:  when we copy a pointer, the value of the pointer is copied. After the copy, the two pointers are distinct.

Comment: I think I know why I'm confused.
Because I think that function is assigning *nPtr = &number, instead of nPtr = &number like the declarations at the top. Which one is right?

Comment: @user3348712: The function is **initializing**, not **assigning**. Initialization in your first example would look like `int *nPtr = &y;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using a pass-by-reference parameter, you force your function not the copy the value of the parameter itself, instead, to use the actual variable you provide. So, for a more clear view, see below:

```
void function( int number )
{
  cout << number;
}

function( myInt ); // function will copy myInt, into its local variables stack
```

but, by using the pass-by-reference method, like this:

```
void function ( int & number )
{
  cout << number
}

function( myInt ); // function will not copy myInt into its local variables stack, instead, it will use the already existent myInt variable.
```

There is no difference in how to compiler will work with pass-by-pointer and pass-by-reference parameters. Instead, the call of your function will look like so:

```
void function_p( int *number )
{
  cout << *number;
}

void function_r( int & number )
{
  cout << number;
}

// and the calls

function_p( &myInt ); // it is required to use address-of operator here
function_r( myInt ); // the effect will be the same, but with less effort in writing that address-of operator
```

In C++11, programmers started to use pass-by-reference method, in general, ordinarily because it has an easier writing "template".

---

To complete the answer to your question, the `*` and `&` operators refer only to the type of the parameter, so that they create compound types. A compound type is a type that is defined in terms of another type. C++ has several compound types, two of which are references and pointers.

You can understand that they only affect the type of a variable (in our case, a parameter), by writing them in a proper way:

```
int* p1; // we will read this: pointer p1 points to an int
int* p2 = &var1; // we read this: pointer p2 points to int variable var1

int var1 = 12;
int& ref1 = var1; // and we read this: ref1 is a reference to var1
```

You can generally consider references represent a different for the same block of memory.

Comment: so the * and & operators only refer to the type of the variable not the actual value of the parameter? 
For visualizing reason, can I see it as:  
void function_p( (int *)number ) and 
void function_r( (int &) number )

Comment: exactly. the `*` and `&` represent the method for creating compound types. for example, an `int` is an ordinary type, and `int*` is a compund type

Comment: That makes sense! I was getting confused because I thought that function_ p was assigning * number = &myInt. Now I understand int * is just the type and that number =&myInt.

Answer (score 0):

you did mean

```
void functions (int &ref)
{
    ref = ref * ref;
}
```

that's how you use refs, avoiding all the '*'s of pointers syntax

Answer (score -1):

This is another of those quirky things of C++. Passing by reference is not the same as passing a pointer. When you do something like

```
void functions (int &ref)
```

You can pass an actual variables into `functions` (rather than pointers to them) like

```
int a = 12;
functions(a);
```

And inside the function you have no need to dereference. Notice that you are passing *by* reference, rather than passing *a* reference.

When you pass a reference, or pointer to something, you use star as such

```
void function( int *nPtr)
```

And thus you have to dereference with a *

Note also that you *get the reference* to a variable (or constant) by putting `&` in front of it, but you *declare* a reference or pointer by putting a `*` in front of it. At the same time, you dereference a pointer also by putting a `*` in front of it.

Comment: Sorry, wrong, and your compiler should have told you that. `functions` can change `ref`, and obviously you can't change 12. And for the same reason, pass-by-reference doesn't pass an actual integer value, it passes a reference to an integer object. As for the the second part: References and pointers are 2 different things, and you are seriously confusing them

Comment: You are right, I didnt think it through when I made the post